# Symfony validate telephone in form field

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have Symfony 2.6 and form for Personal Information in form field telephone, like rhis

```
+38 (918) 280-1594
```

and if developer write "_" or more digits, space. How in action I check this ?
Like developer write

```
+38 (918) 2 801_594
```

And I set in DB

```
+38(918)2801594
```

what are the processes and decisions or bundles to solve this problem?

```
->add('telephone', null, array('label' => 'Telephone', 'max_length' => 255, 'required' => false));

$builder->get('telephone')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
    // transform <br/> to \n so the textarea reads easier
    function ($originalDescription) {
        return preg_replace('/[^0-9()]+/', "", $originalDescription);
    },
    function ($submittedDescription) {
        // remove most HTML tags (but not br,p)
        $cleaned = strip_tags($submittedDescription, '<br><br/><p>');
        // transform any \n to real <br/>
        return str_replace("\n", '<br/>', $cleaned);
    }
));
```

But how it works? I write telephone 65454### and this "#" write in my DB this is wrong. Why I not Understand? And I need determine the number of digits (12 digits). Maybe Example please.

I post +30632666$$# and in DB set this +30632666$$# but in form visible this 30632666 this is exactly I need in my DB, I need set in database correct telephone and limit 13 chars - one "+" and 12 - digital

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After installing the [MisdPhoneNumberBundle](https://github.com/misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle#installation), you can use the bundle's validator:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Validator\Constraints as MisdAssert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table
 */
class Entity
{

  // ...

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
   * @MisdAssert\PhoneNumber()
   */
  private $phone;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [MisdPhoneNumberBundle](https://github.com/misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle), it gives you all you need regarding phone numbers and Symfony.

Comment: How I do solve my problem if I use this bundle ? I need add assert in field my entity or use in form? Example please

Comment: I add in filed entity `    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="phone_number")
     */
    protected $telephone;` and in form `->add('phone_number', 'tel', array('default_region' => 'GB', 'format' => PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL))` and now error

Comment: type field, I check. But I want simple solution. I need 12 digital and not 
special characters, just digital

Comment: "type field"? Have you got a more complete error message? Do you follow all installation instruction of the bundle? Especially Doctrine mapping, and update you database schema.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand by what mean you're trying to replace `#` by something else. If this is the `preg_replace` call, it is not amazing that it does not work, as you're looking for a string that looks like:

```
#<br, (optional spaces), (Maybe /), >#
```

If you want to replace `<br/>` by `\n` like the comment says, you need to put this pattern:

```
/<br\s*\/?\s*>/i
```

Note the `/` at start and end to limit the pattern, and `i` at the end means any case match.

If you want to replace `#`, spaces and `_`, I think that the best would be to replace any character which is not a number of `(`, `)`. In which case this regexp should work (not tested):

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9()]+/', "", $originalDescription);
```

Which means: replace any sequence of 1 or more character which NOT (because of '^') in `0-9`, `(` or `)` by an empty string.

Comment: this is good but I post +30632666$$# and in DB set this +30632666$$# but in form visible this 30632666 this is exactly I need in my DB, I need set in database correct telephone and limit 13 chars - one "+" and 12 - digital

Comment: help please  I post +30632666$$# and in DB set this +30632666$$# but in form visible this 30632666 this is exactly I need in my DB

Answer (score 0):

You should use Symfony [Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) for this task.